# Statement block not reached after for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, syntax-error

I am trying to add search option in my database, I have created the following program, but it is giving me an error message on loop portion, I am unable to understand why its not moving towards else statement. Kindly check it and tell me where I am making mistake.

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    if (isset ($_POST['username']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $query = "select * from users where username like '%$username%' ";

        if ($query_result = mysql_query($query))
        {
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query_result);
            if ($numrows > 1)
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
                {
                    echo $query_result = mysql_result($query_result, $i, 'username');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'No Results Found!';
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No Results Found!!';
            // echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Are you kidding with me !';
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. **[Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) can help you decide which.

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is about overwriting the `$query_result variable`, whereas the other one is about the query returning `false` to indicate an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your loop you're doing:

```
echo $query_result=     mysql_result($query_result,$i,'username');
```

Which doesn't add up: you're `echho`-ing the result of an assignment. Not just any assignment, too. You're reassigning the return value of `mysql_result` to the resource: `$query_result`. Therefore, on the second iteration of your loop, the `mysql_result` call will fail.

That said, the `mysql_*` extension is *Deprecated* and shouldn't be used anymore, look into the preferred alternative extensions, like `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.
you could also rewrite your loop as a `while`-loop, using:

```
$out = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result))
{
    $out .= $row['username'].'<br/>';
}
```

*On your query:*
Instead of doing `SELECT *`, which basically selects all fields for every row matching your `WHERE` clause, if all you're interested in is the username (which, from your code seems to be the case), why not simply use `SELECT username`. That's easier on your DB, and doesn't require as much resources.

Your `WHERE` clause reads `username LIKE '%{$var}%'`, this means that, if the input were `a`, your query returns all usernames containing an `a` somewhere. Apart from that being not too secure, it also is dead-slow. Your query is highly likely to perform a full table scan, probably requiring I/O disk operations. Either use `like` without `%` wildcards to ensure case-insensitivity, use the single-char wildcard `_` or, if needs must, only use one `%`. A username search for *"sup"* that yields *"superman"* makes more sense than the same search yielding *"dinnersupper"*

Lastly, you're code is *extremely* vulnerable [to mysql-injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). If I were to post the username: `'; DROP TABLE users; --`, your query would look like this:

```
select * from users where username like '%'; DROP TABLE users; -- %'
```

Which spells disaster, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You call in a loop `mysql_result` and replace the query resource `$query_result` with the value of the cell. On the next call `$query_result` won't be a valid resource anymore.

Note: not sure what you're trying to do as you don't even use the value... simply remove the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few line of code..i change your loop into a while loop..try this one..

```
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
          echo $rs['username'] . " <br>";
        }
    }
```

hope it help...